# Insert multiple records in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am using oracle sql developer to insert rows in my database.

While this request is working :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME) VALUES (1,"ok1")
```

The second one (when I am trying to insert multiple rows)is not working:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME) VALUES (1,"ok1"),(2,"ok2")
```

I am getting this error :

```
Erreur SQL : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Comment: that's mysql extended inserted syntax. it doesn't work anywhere but mysql.

Comment: @MarcB: it's also supported in **SQL Server** in versions **2008** and newer

Comment: @marc_b: it's actually ANSI SQL, not tied to specific DBMS - but not all DBMS support it. And Oracle is one of them.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `INSERT ALL` statement. For example:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val1.1', 'val1.2', 'val1.3')
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val2.1', 'val2.2', 'val2.3')
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val3.1', 'val3.2', 'val3.3')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support multi-row inserts. You need to write one `insert` per row:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME) VALUES (1,'ok1');
INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME) VALUES (2,'ok2');
```

Additionally: string literals need to be enclosed in **single** quotes in SQL. Double quotes are for identifiers. `"ok1"` is a column name, `'ok1'` is a string constant.

Answer (score 0):

See this recent post for some other ways to enter test data as well:
[Insert same data multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477120/insert-same-data-multiple-times/26534953#26534953)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about SQL injection then run the following :

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME) VALUES (1,'ok1');
INSERT INTO TABLE ( USERID, USERNAME) VALUES (2,'ok2');
END;
```