# SQL Multiple Insert into multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into a table without specifying the column names, however, I get an error on the first comma that its a partially recognized rule and it's giving me an error

```
INSERT INTO MY_EMPLOYEE
VALUES(126,'Popov', 'Olga', 'opopov', 8500), 
    (127, 'Chen', 'Ling', 'lcheng', 14500), 
    (128, 'Dunn', 'David', 'ddunn', NULL);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26612365/4899193

Comment: Is this something that you need to do only once of are you writing an application that will be put into the hands of lots of people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that Oracle supports `VALUES` with multiple records.  Here is a simple alternative:

```
INSERT INTO MY_EMPLOYEE
    SELECT 126,'Popov', 'Olga', 'opopov', 8500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 127, 'Chen', 'Ling', 'lcheng', 14500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
    SELECT 128, 'Dunn', 'David', 'ddunn', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Note:  I do highly recommend that you specify the columns for the insert, but that is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
INSERT INTO MY_EMPLOYEE(col1_name,col2_name,col3_name,col4_name,col5_name)
VALUES(126,'Popov', 'Olga', 'opopov', 8500), 
    (127, 'Chen', 'Ling', 'lcheng', 14500), 
    (128, 'Dunn', 'David', 'ddunn', NULL);
```

Comment: This is MySQL syntax, the question is about Oracle that doesn't support inserting multiple rows this way.